Bliss os error on installation
When I tried to install bliss os it showed the following error:
Cannot mount /dev/sda2
Do you want to force format it to ext4 ?
This is when I chose the partition for installing bliss os after selecting EFI folder and I cannot get to the update message.I tried to again do it with reinstalling the iso but to no success. It also deleted my windows 10 directory and my laptop cannot be used now.

Hi! Welcome here. Sad to hear that your laptop currently cannot be used. I had to look up "bliss OS". Intersting. It's a very untypical Linux distribution, maybe that's why it's not very well-known and there's some rough edges on the installation. I'm sorry to hear this affects you negatively! So, first step probably is to re-establish usefulness of your laptop. If you still need Windows, this is the time to reinstall it, before doing anything else.
